# Windows tool minimizing apps to notification area by closing them?

Tags: windows, notification, minimization

[TrayIt!](https://winaero.com/blog/minimize-apps-to-system-tray-notification-area-with-trayit/) can minimize apps to system tray (notification area), but it can't do the same when with the close button. Is there a tool that makes the act of closing an app become minimizing it to the notification area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This AutoHotKey script makes the act of clicking the close button becomes minimizing the window to the taskbar. Together with TrayIt!, the whole process will minimizing it to the notification area.

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

; Add the ahk_class of the windows you want  minimize by clicking on the close button in this array:
Classes := "Notepad,CabinetWClass,IEFrame" ; ...
Loop, parse, Classes, `,
    GroupAdd, GroupName, ahk_class %A_LoopField%

SetTimer CheckMouse, -300
return

CheckMouse:
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, mX, mY, WindowUnderMouse
    WinGetPos, wX, wY, wW, wH, ahk_id %WindowUnderMouse%
        CloseButton := (mY > wY and mY < wY+50 and (mX > wX + (wW-50) and mX < wX+wW))
    SetTimer CheckMouse, -300
return

#If (CloseButton)

    ~LButton::
        MouseGetPos,,, WindowUnderMouse
        WinGetClass, Class, ahk_id %WindowUnderMouse%
        If Class in %Classes%
        {
            WinGet, id, ID, ahk_id %WindowUnderMouse%
            DISABLE_CloseButton(id)
            WinMinimize, ahk_id %WindowUnderMouse%
        }
    return


#If WinActive("ahk_group GroupName")

    !F4:: WinMinimize, A

#If ; turn off context sensitivity


DISABLE_CloseButton(id){ ;By RealityRipple at http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-258725.html   
  menu:=DllCall("user32\GetSystemMenu","UInt",id,"UInt",0)
  DllCall("user32\DeleteMenu","UInt",menu,"UInt",0xF060,"UInt",0x0)
  WinGetPos,x,y,w,h,ahk_id %id%
  WinMove,ahk_id %id%,,%x%,%y%,%w%,% h-1
  WinMove,ahk_id %id%,,%x%,%y%,%w%,% h+1
}

ENABLE_CloseButton(id){ ;By Mosaic1 at http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-258725.html  
  menu:=DllCall("user32\GetSystemMenu","UInt",id,"UInt",1)
  DllCall("user32\DrawMenuBar","UInt",id)
}
```

Original post and the explanation for how the script works is from this Stack Overflow post: [How to minimize a window by closing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53405915/3416774)

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work with ManicTime